# how to use Urban Airship Deep link in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, urbanairship.com

How to handle Urban airship deep link in ios, how to recieve the configured deep link in the notification, I can able to send the deeplink through urban airship,once notification receives which method should i use to handle the deeplink.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions.

#### Solution 1: Use custom-url schemes

Add a [custom url scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10) to your application. Then make all deep links from a Urban Airship push message contain this custom url scheme.

Urban Airship automatically calls open application on this deep link and thereby enacting the deep link on your app.

#### Solution 2: Use UAPushNotificationDelegate

Add your class as a push notification delegate of `UAPush` singleton.

```
- (void)initializePushMessageService {
    
    [UAirship takeOff];
    [UAPush shared].pushNotificationDelegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - UAPushNotificationDelegate

- (void)launchedFromNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
          fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
 
    if([self hasDeeplink:notification]) {
        
        NSString *deeplink = [self deepLinkPathFromNotification:notification];

        //do something with the deeplink
    }
}

#define kUrbanAirshipDeepLinkKey    @"^d"
- (BOOL)hasDeeplink:(NSDictionary *)notification {
    return notification[kUrbanAirshipDeepLinkKey] != nil;
}

- (NSString *)deepLinkPathFromNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification {
    return notification[kUrbanAirshipDeepLinkKey];
}
```

Comment: The second approach conflicts with the built in actions. It would be better to provide a custom action that deals with the deep link: http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/ios-deep-linking.html#customizing-the-deep-link-action